# Java recursion code

Tags: java

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(recursion(1, 100));
        System.out.println(recursion(4, 5));
        System.out.println(recursion(99, 100));
        System.out.println(recursion(100, 100));
    }

    public static int recursion(int m, int n) {
        int number = 0;
        if (m == 1) {
            number = ((2 * n) - 1);
        } else {
            number = 2 * recursion(m - 1, n - 1);
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the last two tests return 0's and I know they are supposed to be big numbers, is that why? How can I figure out the value of the last two??

Comment: what is "the second two " ?

Comment: Might be the last two method calling. :)

Comment: the second two results

Comment: You can easily find out the reason by debugging the code. Just add a breakpoint on the return statement.

Answer (score 7):

You're running into arithmetic overflow.  An `int` can only store values between -2^31 and 2^31-1.  To deal with numbers this big, you need a more suitable data type, such as `BigInteger`.

Comment: Would I just replace BigInteger for every int?

Comment: Oh, you were 5 minutes earlier, sorry, when I started answering your answer was absent.

Comment: In your case the result grows as ~ 2^m, which is really fast. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: The BigInteger class implements the aritmetic operations as methods, so instead of `m - 1` you have `m.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)` --- take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: It says "cannot invoke subtract(BigInteger) on the primitive type int" so I tried different things but it's still giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

At some point you number exceeded maximum for int type. Then the result of multiplication turns negative, then - zero.

```
m = 31, n = 32 : number = -1073741824
m = 32, n = 33 : number = -2147483648
```

Next step you multiply them (m = 33, n = 34):

```
System.out.println((-1073741824) * (-2147483648));
```

Which is 0.

Starting from this point everything is 0.

Comment: do you know what the final answer for the problem is though?